# An Efficient Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is for my infix.
>
> My suffix recalls a baritone or a bass.
>
> My whole is quite dreamy - what am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My prefix is for my infix.

> If you're **ill**, you may need a **pill**.

My suffix recalls a baritone or a bass.

> **low**

My whole is quite dreamy - what am I?

> A **pillow**.